# Automatically Generating an Email Notification When Certifications are Expiring

Tags: validation, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an excel spreadsheet containing the expiration dates for all certifications for each member of my team. As the expiration approaches, the cell automatically color shifts based on the remaining validity of the certification.

What I am looking to do is send an email notification when the certification is expiring in 90 days or less.

```
function sendEmail() {
  // EMAIL Check & Date
  // Fetch Cert Dates & Employees
  var CertExpiration = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(4,3,11,9); //All Cert Dates on Sheet
  var CertDate = CertExpiration.getValue(); // Get Certificate Date as a value
  var Employee = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(4,2,9,1); //Retrieve list of employee Names
  var EmployeeName = Employee.getValue(); // Set variable for email notification
  var Today = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(2,2,1,1); // Sets Today to Today() on sheet
  // Check Cert Expiration
  if (CertDate - Today < 90);  
    {
    // Fetch the email address
     var emailAddress = 'Example@Example.com';
    // Send Alert Email.
    var message = 'Certificate for ' + EmployeeName + ' expiring soon'; //
    var subject = 'CERT EXPIRING SOON | CV CERT TRACKING';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
   
    }
}
```

I would like this email to contain a list of all EmployeeName that match the condition (CertDate - Today <90) if possible. Additionally, a method by which to prevent the email from being sent multiple times. Currently, the email sends successfully, but only contains the first referenced EmployeeName.

[image: Reference Document]

Comment: You can put what ever in the message , not only employeename.     var message = 'Certificate for ' + EmployeeName + values_you_want + ' expiring soon'; // if you want to use template. You can use a HTML template to fill the content.

Comment: Thanks Kat, but the message is fine as is. The issue I am having is that EmployeeName prints only 1 value, and not the entire range of values within the variable that match the condition. Perhaps I am approaching this from the wrong direction?

Comment: var EmployeeName = Employee.getValues();   Try getValues() instead of getValue()

Comment: Thanks Kat, the email now lists all values for that variable. Now how do I go about restricting it to only include values for EmployeeName that have a value for CertDate < 90 in the same row?

Comment: see the answer I posted. I do not know your data structure.  So you still have to make some changes on the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you need a loop function to go through all your data.

```
function sendEmail() {
   const data =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(4,2,11,9).getValues();
   for (let i = 0; i< data.length ;i++){
    //change the [i][0] the second number in [] to the actual index of your number column.  If your column number is 5, then the index will be 4
    //index start from 0.
    const EmployeeName = data[i][0];
    const CertDates = data[i].slice(1);
    const Today = new Date()
    //this arr will hold each cert date less than 90 days. 
    const arr = [];
    for(let j=0; j<CertDates.length ;j++ ){
      const CertDate = CertDates[j];
      if(typeof(CertDate)== 'object' && Math.floor((CertDate  - Today ) / (1000*60*60*24)) < 90){
        console.log(CertDate)
        arr.push(CertDate);
      }
    }

    //if any emlpoyees has expire date less than 90 days. 1 or many. It will send email to employee name.
    if(arr.length>0){
      // Fetch the email address
      var emailAddress = 'Example@Example.com';
      // Send Alert Email.
      var message = 'Certificate for ' + EmployeeName + ' expiring soon'; //
      var subject = 'CERT EXPIRING SOON | CV CERT TRACKING';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the assistance Kat. I have attached a reference image for the document in question, where A-K are the names of the employees. 

With this in mind, I would change "const EmployeeName = date[i][0]" to "const EmployeeName = date[i][1]" as column B is the EmployeeName location.

However, how do I enter the cert dates as a range of values?

Comment: which column is holding the cert date for employee?

Comment: Cert Dates are in columns C-K for each individual, or index value 2-10. There is an image of the spreadsheet in the main post if that helps.

Comment: Let me know if I was wrong.  So Range C-E is for ASBESTOS, F-H is for AHERA. Is that right?   It that's the case, codes above needs to be updated.

Comment: Okay, so far with some tinkering I have it somewhat where I need to be. "const data =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(4,2,11,9).getValues();" gets me the EmployeeName column correctly. 

The range only needs to include (c4:k14) the actual certificate expirations. Ideally, the functionality is: If a certificate in Employee A row is expired, send email stating Employee A has certificate expiring soon. So if any of the dates are within 90days, send an email about that employee.

Comment: So column B (A B C D E F G  Is the employee name), C-K is the cert date.   Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. Thank you so much for helping me understand this. It's a bit beyond what I am familiar with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242699/discussion-between-kreinas-and-liquidkat).